# Need clarification on addAll methods behaviour

Tags: java, list, collections, arraylist

Hi i am using addAll method of Collection framework. Please find below my code. It is working fine for code 1. For code 2 it is giving me compilation error. I dont know why it didnt give me error for code 1. Kindly give the reason for this.

code 1

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> firstList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List secondList=new ArrayList();                        //without generic

    secondList.add("string value");

    firstList.addAll(secondList);
    System.out.println(firstList);

}
```

Output:

```
[string value]
```

Code 2

```
         public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> firstList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<String> secondList=new ArrayList<String>();        //with generic  

    secondList.add("string value");

    firstList.addAll(secondList);
    System.out.println(firstList);

}
```

Output

```
     compilation error
```

Comment: You are trying to add String list into a Integer list, it is not possible. That's the best use of Generics, you will get this mismatch as an error during compilation time itself.

Comment: You're using the raw type in example one. You can add anything to that list, but can't make any assumptions about the elements type when `get()`ting them. It's inherently type unsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java `Generics` are checked on compile time. means compiler can check the generic list and can show an error if String `List` is to `Integer`. While in the first case . it is a `non-generic`, which compiler cannot judge at compile time.
Also read about `Type Erasure`

Answer (score 0):

```
 firstList.addAll(secondList);
```

`firstList` is type of string

`secondList` is type of numbers

In the first example you are using raw type but in the second you are using generics(specified list is for strings)

[**SEE HERE**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

If you use generics checking donet at compile time .If you use raw list it will done at runtime

Answer (score 0):

```
List secondList=new ArrayList();                        //without generic
```

It means `List<Object> secondList=new ArrayList<Object>();` so you can add any object to this.

But if you explicitly mention the type it is clear that you can't add string to integer list, in your second case

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add all values from `String` bucket to a bucket which is specially allocated for `Integer`.

You can do like this

```
ArrayList commonList =new ArrayList(); // for all objects
List<String> stringList =new ArrayList<String>();        
List<Integer> integerList =new ArrayList<Integer>();     
stringList.add("string value");
integerList.add(1);
commonList .addAll(stringList);
commonList .addAll(integerList);
System.out.println(commonList );
```